# 2 form elements and one link from a Not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a login form on a site that is using bootstrap. On desktop there is no problem. But on mobile devices the button doesn't work nor does the checkbox. There is also a link for the forgotten password but that doesn't work on mobile either.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-8">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:10px;" placeholder="User Name" aria-label="User Name" name="username"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="true" name="login_now"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" name="password"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button role="button" class="btn btn-blue" type="submit" aria-label="Log In" name="login_button">Log In</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="checkbox" name="save-password" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Save Password (do not check box if using a public computer)&nbsp;
                <a class="password-link" href="forgot_password.php">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have no idea why this isn't working on mobile, but is working on desktop

Comment: What mobile device are you using?

Comment: one IPhone (Not mine) Opera on an Edge+ and Opera on a Nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seemed to have been the col-xs-8 at the top. It seemed to have caused the input to overlap the button